# Decrease Long Build Time in Gulp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, gulp

My build task is as below. For each changes in any file, it takes about 30s-60s for each time. It is too long for development. How can I improve it? Or is there any way to see changes in development enviroment, quickly?

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      filePath + '/Scripts/js/desktop/pages/Index.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concatJs("app.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(filePath + '/scripts/js/desktop/bundle'))
    .pipe(rollup({
      allowRealFiles: true,
      "format": "iife",
      "plugins": [
        resolve({
          module: true,
          browser:true
        }),
        commonjs({
            namedExports: {
                'node_modules/react/react.js': ['Component', 'Children', 'createElement', 'PropTypes']
            }
        }),
        require("rollup-plugin-babel")({
          "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }]],
          "plugins": ["external-helpers"],
          "exclude": './node_modules/**'
        }),
        replace({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'production' )
        })
      ],
      entry: filePath + '/scripts/js/desktop/bundle/app.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(filePath + '/build/scripts/'));
});
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import Index from '../pages/MyAccount/Index';
import FAQ from '../pages/FAQ/Index';
import Header from '../components/Header/Header';
import Breadcrumb from '../components/Breadcrumb/Breadcrumb';
import Footer from '../components/Footer/Footer';
import reducers from '../../reducers/index';


const store = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

class Pager extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){

            const history = createHistory();

            return (
                <Provider store={store(reducers)}>
                        <Router history={history}>
                            <div>
                                <Header />
                                <div className="hb-container">
                          <Breadcrumb id={1}/>
                        </div>
                                <div className="clearfix"></div>
                                <div className="hb-container">
                                    <Route path="/hesabim" component={Index}  />
                                    <Route path="/yardim" component={FAQ}  />
                                </div>
                                <Footer/>
                            </div>
                        </Router>
                </Provider>
        );
    }

};

let root = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<Pager {...(root.dataset) } />,
root);
```

After building, app.js is about 810 KB.

Comment: That's a lot! Rollup shouldn't take longer than a few seconds (at most) on on average web app. It'll be hard to debug this without more information and without the application itself so consider adding loggers along your pipe to see how long each step is taking, then narrowing down on the specific step that's bottlenecking you. Check file sizes as well.

Comment: @ZekeDroid I have added  content of index.js in question. And after building, size of app.js about 810 KB. I import react, react-dom, redux, react-router, axios, history and redux-promise in project.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question specifically, BUT! I'll just throw it out there in the comments.

Webpack has incremental builds, which is fantastic and avoids this problem all together. I used to use gulp, but have found webpack much better. Don't have an answer for your problem, but webpack is pretty great and avoids a lot of these things.

Comment: You mean webpack over rollup ;) Yes, webpack is definitely easier to use, but there are also reasons to use rollup instead. @KamuranSönecek, still not sure we could help without figuring out the bottleneck. Try logging the time it takes between each pipe step, please

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc thanks for your advice. I will valuate webpack, It will may be better than gulp.

Comment: @ZekeDroid  I check pipe, and their logs : concatJs 246ms, gulp.dest 9ms, rollup 24.631ms, gulp.dest 12ms. Rollup is too slow

Comment: 24 milliseconds sounds pretty fast to me. it seems like there's something else taking long. Does it maybe take a long time to START gulp? this can sometimes happen when you're loading polyfills or large libraries in your gulpfile

Comment: oh my bad, i just realized you meant 24 thousand. Yeah, rollup is definitely your bottleneck. That's a start! Not sure what else could be the cause. My suggestion is for you to start removing code until it can run fast enough, then see where it might be taking long. For example, that first part where you're loading something called `root.dataset` seems kinda strange. Try not passing that prop